# onclick checkbox display data - unchecking the common file should keep displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**working up to:**
When onclick checkbox data will display common & data both as i have mentioned in the snippet.

**Problem is**
When you will uncheck there should be a reverse process of checking.

for example when I checked on 
"one" then line one & three is displayed.
"two" then all three lines are displaying.

But when **I uncheck "two/one" the common line no three should be displayed.**

So my problem on **unchecking the common file should keep displaying.**

Please, can anyone help me regarding this problem?

```js
// onclick checkbox display files to upload

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {

    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
    var chkId = $(this).attr("id");

    if (document.getElementById(chkId).checked == true) {
      $('.' + inputValue).fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
      $('.' + inputValue).fadeOut('slow');
    }


    //  alert("Id: " + chkId + " Value: " + inputValue);

  });
});
```

```css
legend {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.fileupload {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>please mark on?</legend>

      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3 ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox1" value="one">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox1">checked one </label>
      </div>

      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox2" value="two">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox2">checked-two</label>
      </div>




    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Result </legend>

      <div class="fileupload one">checked - one </div>
      <div class="fileupload two">checked - two </div>
      <div class="fileupload one two">One Or/and Two</div>


    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by below.

on clicking on the checkbox

- Hide all the result messages
- Get the value from all the input boxes that are checked and save it to array
- Iterate over array and display the results

```js
// onclick checkbox display files to upload
$(document).ready( function() {
showMessageOnCheckboxChange();
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click( function() {
    showMessageOnCheckboxChange();
});
});

function showMessageOnCheckboxChange() {
// hide all results
$('.fileupload').fadeOut('fast');
var inputs = $('.custom-control-input');
var toShow = new Array();
inputs.each( function( index, obj ) {      
    var input = $(obj);
    if (input.prop('checked') == true) {
       toShow.push(input.attr('value'));   
    }
});
// show results
for (sh in toShow) {
    $('.' + toShow[sh]).fadeIn('slow');
}
}
```

```css
legend {
font-size: 14px;
}

.fileupload {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>please mark on?</legend>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3 ">  
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox1" value="one">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox1">checked one</label>
        </div>

        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox2" value="two">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox2">checked-two</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
</div>


<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Result </legend>

        <div class="fileupload one">checked - one </div>
        <div class="fileupload two">checked - two </div>
        <div class="fileupload one two">One Or/and Two</div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: perfect @sighil, it works & what i wanted... thanks a lot for helping.

This code is not working if i kept anyone checkbox checked by default..please can you help regarding?

Comment: updated the code with the request. On document.ready call the logic to display the message. Use the same function for click as well.

Comment: superb concept @Sighil...Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Check this you have to ADD else part for hide div

```js
// onclick checkbox display files to upload

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {

    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
    var chkId = $(this).attr("id");

    if (document.getElementById(chkId).checked == true) {
      $('.' + inputValue).fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
      var checkedCount =  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
      if(checkedCount && checkedCount.length>0)
       {
         $('.' + inputValue +':not(.one.two)').fadeOut('slow');
       }
      else
        {
         $('.' + inputValue).fadeOut('slow');
        }
    }


    //  alert("Id: " + chkId + " Value: " + inputValue);

  });
});
```

```css
legend {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.fileupload {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>please mark on?</legend>

      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3 ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox1" value="one">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox1">checked one </label>
      </div>

      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox2" value="two">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox2">checked-two</label>
      </div>




    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Result </legend>

      <div class="fileupload one">checked - one </div>
      <div class="fileupload two">checked - two </div>
      <div class="fileupload one two">One Or/and Two</div>


    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes @Siva Rm K it works thanks a lot for helping.

does this code work for checked="checked" attribute? if I keep the first checkbox checked by default the data should display accordingly.

Comment: also sir i don't want to use class name manually in this script because there will be many checkboxes available dynamically

Comment: yes. it would be. for dynamic classes you specify any variable in  "not" css property :not(your variable)' Logic is to skip common div when any of the checkbox is checked.